# Lists in Visual Studio using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, list, event-handling, listboxitem

I'm really quite new to developing apps, but I have some understanding of what I'm doing. I'm using Visual Studio Express for Windows 8

I've created a List (List A) with ListBoxItems which, when someone clicks on them through a PointerPressed Event Handler, items are added to List B through:
ListB.Items.Add("ItemName");

However, I am unable to add an event handler to these ListBoxItems, so if anyone knows a way I can influence other items based on the SelectedItem of List B, that would be greatly appreciated.

Also, I'm pretty sure I should be doing this by a SelectionChanged method, however I have no idea where to go from there. Please try to make it understandable for me as well. Thank you so much.

Comment: Webforms right? Open the code behind and choose the name of the list control from the first drop down menu at thetop of the screen. Next click the second drop down and choose the event. Studio will create everything you need to get started.

Comment: @ColinPear that comment looks like an answer - probably best to put it in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

The SelectionChanged event will give you a heads-up that the user changed the selectedItem from your ListBox.

Then, you can take the listBox.SelectedItem and do whatever you need with it. Like in your case, to add it to the other list.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help. I worked out how to do it.

```
private void ListA_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((string)ListA.SelectedItem == "Item 1")
        {
            ListB.Items.Add("Item A");
        }
```

where the Selection Changed event handler for ListA is ListA_SelectionChanged, Item 1 is an item in ListA and Item A is an Item in List B. Thanks so much.